# Netbeans throwing error about super constructor

Tags: java, inheritance, netbeans, constructor

I'm making a student database application which has different types of students to practice inheritance and get a taste of other OO principles.

I have a few classes which inherit from the super "Student" class. The problem is that I am having trouble getting the subclasses to have overloaded constructors.

Netbeans is fine with the Student constructor apparently, but it tells me in the subclasses that there isn't a suitable constructor found in the Superclass. From that alone I am completely confused.

Here is the code thus far:

```
class MyDB {

    public abstract class Student {
        //Variable declaration
        //
        public String firstName;
        public String lastName;
        public int studentID;
        public float gpa;
        public String status;
        public String mentor;

        //Constructor & overloaded constructors
        //
        public Student(String fn, String ln, int ID, float sgpa, String stat, String m) {
            firstName = fn;
            lastName = ln;
            studentID = ID;
            gpa = sgpa;
            status = stat;
            mentor = m;
        }

        public Student(String fn, String ln) {
            this(fn, ln, 0, 0, "", "");
        }

        //Class Methods
        //
        public abstract float calculateTuition(String status, float numberOfCreditHours);
                        //Tuition is Calculated
                /*
            if(status == "resident") {
                if(undergraduate) {
                  if(tuition) {
                        return numberOfCreditHours * 200;
                    } else {
                        return numberOfCreditHours * 250;
                    }
                } else {
                    return numberOfCreditHours * 300;
                }
            } else {
                if(undergraduate) {
                    if(tuition) {
                        return numberOfCreditHours * 400;
                    } else {
                        return numberOfCreditHours * 450;
                    }   
                } else {
                        return numberOfCreditHours * 350;
                }
            }
        */


                public abstract void update();
            //Database entry is updated
        public abstract void add();
            //Database entry for student is created
        public abstract void delete();
            //Database entry for student is deleted
        public abstract void query();
            //Query to DB is made, then info is returned to the screen
    }

    public class Undergraduate extends Student {
        private String level;
        private final String m;

        public String getLevel() {
            return level;
        }
        public void setLevel(String newLevel) {
            level = newLevel;
        }

                //Overloaded Constructor
        public Undergraduate(String newlevel, String fn, String ln, int ID, float sgpa, String stat, String m) {
        }

        @Override
        public float calculateTuition(String status, float numberOfCreditHours) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void update() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void add() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void delete() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void query() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
    }

    public class Graduate extends Student {
        private String thesisTitle;
        private String thesisAdvisor;

        public String getThesisTitle() {
            return thesisTitle;
        }
        public String getThesisAdvisor() {
            return thesisAdvisor;
        }
        public void setThesisTitle(String newThesisTitle) {
            thesisTitle = newThesisTitle;
        }
        public void setThesisAdvisor(String newThesisAdvisor) {
            thesisAdvisor = newThesisAdvisor;
        }

                //Overloaded Constructor

        @Override
        public float calculateTuition(String status, float numberOfCreditHours) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void update() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void add() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void delete() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void query() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
    }

    public class PartTime extends Student {
        private String company;
                    //Name of sponsoring employer

        public String getCompany() {
            return company;
        }
        public void setCompany(String newCompany) {
            company = newCompany;
        }

                //Overloaded Constructor

        @Override
        public float calculateTuition(String status, float numberOfCreditHours) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void update() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void add() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void delete() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void query() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
    }




    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

please ignore the override statements. they look messy because I let netbeans auto do whatever it wanted to get rid of errors.

There is more to be done with the application, but for now the issue is with the constructors.

Tutorials and questions I have checked usually deal with overriding constructors of the same class, or subclasses that don't override constructors.

Comment: Compile errors are *printed,* not 'thrown'. Exceptions are thrown.

Answer (score 2):

Your subclass must call one of its parent constructors. This is done implicitly when classes have a default (no-arg) constructor. Since `Student` does not have a no-arg constructor, then whatever extends from it must call one of its constructors in their constructor, such as

```
public class Undergraduate extends Student {
    public Undergraduate() {
        super(null, null);
    }
    public Undergraduate(String fn, String ln) {
        super(fn, ln);
    }
    //...
}
```

Otherwise, just add a default constructor to `Student`:

```
protected Student() {
    this(null, null);
}
```

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I felt there might be something missing from Student, even though it was accepted by netbeans. Do you know of a good resource I might be able to get a better understanding of this? The oracle documentation didn't have this in one specific article that I could find. At least not the beginner oracle documentation.